# sonar default port is not available

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed sonar on my machine and started the service

I also configured the sonar.properties file as follows:

```
# Listen host/port and context path (for example / or /sonar). Default values are  0.0.0.0:9000/.
#sonar.web.host:                           0.0.0.0
sonar.web.port:                            9300
#sonar.web.context:                        /
```

But then when i try to access the application using "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9300/sonar"

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /. Reason: 

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

I also copied the sonar.war file under the webapps directory of apache tomcat then   when i try to access the application i get the following error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
type     Status report 
message /sonar/ description The requested resource is not available.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
```

Please can someone help me on this

Comment: Please improve the description of your issue, your post is incomplete. (you're talking about deployment on Tomcat in the 2nd part of your post, but you display a message from Jetty...)

Comment: sorry following is the error                                           HTTP Status 404 - /sonar/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /sonar/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.30

Comment: Please add more information if you wanna get helped: your message just shows that Sonar could not start. You should have a look into Sonar log files to know what's going on.

Comment: obligatory `check your log files`. Error codes are for the end user to see that something unexpected happened, the actual log files are where you are going to see _what_ happened. ( just realized this post is 4 years old... why was it top post... )

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify any value in the web context, you should try to access Sonar by typing "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9300" and not "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9300/sonar"

Comment: Hello let me start a fresh, first i m trying to access sonar as a standalone and not behind tomcat so i edited the sonar.properties file as follows                                                    # Listen host/port and context path (for example / or /sonar). Default values are 0.0.0.0:9000/. sonar.web.host: 10.217.14.40 sonar.web.port: 32020 sonar.web.context: /sonar                                            Next i m trying to access the page through http://10.217.14.40:32020/sonar  but i am getting HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /sonar. Reason: Service Unavailable

Comment: @user1670818 In that case, have you tried `http://10.217.14.40:32020` instead of `http://10.217.14.40:32020/sonar` ?